# I've been trying to make a json file out of a list that has dictionaries

Tags: python

For example
I have tried

```py
import json
data = [{"ModelCode":"VH017","MakeCode":"VM020","VehicleTypeCode":"VC00000052","Year":2017,"IsActive":true,"RegistrationNumber":"KCC 254 ZY","IsApproved":true,"ApprovedBy":null,"Color":"BLUE","Id":"8c5062da-727b-40d5-b763-408cafdc53d8","_id":"3ce92939-4df7-4b9e-af48-647e218736da"},{"ModelCode":"VH024","MakeCode":"VM026","VehicleTypeCode":"VC00000053","Year":2008,"IsActive":false,"RegistrationNumber":"kkk 333k","IsApproved":false,"ApprovedBy":null,"Color":"blue","Id":"8c5062da-727b-40d5-b763-408cafdc53d8"}]
data_from_api = data.strip('][').split(',')
json.loads(data_from_api)
print(data_from_api)
```

I get a "NameError: name 'true' is not defined"

Comment: `true` and `false` should be `True` and `False` in Python.  If the data was originally a JSON string, just call `json.loads` on the original string and don't mess about with stripping and splitting.

Comment: I'm still running into the same error

Comment: `data` should be a string.

Comment: `null` should be None, and `data_from_api` should be a string as well. wrap it like `str(data)` and it should be okay.

Comment: I would like to use dictionary methods on this data, is there no way of cleaning up this data?

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads(str)` is used to import data from a json string. If you want to create a json string from python data to save in a file as your header suggest then use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dumps) instead.

And as comments suggest. In python null is spelled `None`, false is `False` and true is `True`

```py
import json
data = [
    {
        "ModelCode":"VH017",
        "IsActive":True,
        "ApprovedBy":None
    },{
        "ModelCode":"VH024",
        "IsActive":False,
        "ApprovedBy":None
    }
]
json_str = json.dumps(data)
print(json_str)
```